# How to set the color of a Google Calendar that was created via the API

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the google calendar API with PHP. I know how to create a new calendar, but how do I set the color of the calendar I've created? I've been searching for hours. I've tried

```
$calendar -> setColor();
```

I've tried

```
$calendar -> setColorId();
```

both of which are undefined methods. I found documentation on how to [modify the color definitions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors). And sent the color of an event with

```
$event -> setColorId();
```

But I can't find anything anywhere about how to set the color of a calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can change the color of the calendar by using [CalendarList: update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/update).

It is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#calendar_and_calendar_list) that `CalendarList` is a collection of all calendar entries that a user has added to their list (shown in the left panel of the web UI). You can use it to add and remove existing calendars to/from the users’ list. You also use it to retrieve and set the values of user-specific calendar properties, such as default reminders. Another example is *foreground color*, since different users can have different colors set for the same calendar.

Also, The Calendar API now includes fields for custom [colors](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors) for calendars. The [CalendarList](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) resource now includes `backgroundColor` and `foregroundColor` properties that supersede `colorId`. To use the new custom colors, set `colorRgbFormat` to `True` when performing updates.

Source: [What's New in v3 - Custom colors for Calendars](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/whats-new)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @KENdi accepted answer I had hard time figuring out the syntax. For anyone who want quick PHP solution:

`$updatedCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->update($calendarListEntry->getId(), $calendarListEntry, array("colorRgbFormat" => true));`

Where `$calendarListEntry` is the **calendarList** object you can get by using *get* method.

This enables using `$calendarListEntry->setBackgroundColor("$calColor);` where `$calColor` is a string containing hexa-color code, eg. *7e7e7e*.